# Visual Studio debugger no longer showing lines of code preceding line of code where crash happens

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I while ago when I had a crash in Visual Studio it would show me the lines where the code crashed as well as all the lines before that that called the function containing the line on which the code crashed.

Since a few months and a few updates in Visual Studio, it started showing only the line on which the crash happens. For example, my code is crashing and the debugger has opened the header file and is showing the line in there where the code crashed but it is not showing the lines that call the function in that header. Previously it would show the lines that call the function, starting from the main function of the program in which the header is used. And I could easily workout which part of the main program is making a bad call to the function in the header.

Is there a way to have it show me all the lines like before? I've searched everywhere online and cannot find this.

[image]

Comment: Is the call stack window still present? Can you share an image of it to better explain!?

Comment: How do I share an image, please?

Comment: Edit your question, then click on "Image" in the tool bar directly above your question.

Comment: Thanks. I have uploaded the image.

Comment: There's still a call stack tab down there, but you should use the Debug configuration for debugging, not Release. Regardless of whether it helps with this particular issue, it will improve the debugging experience a lot.

Comment: What about the bottom right pane, tab "Call Stack"!?

Comment: I was able to find how to display the call stack window: while debugging, in the Debug menu, select Windows > Call Stack. Problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: If you solved it, you can now either delete the question or write an answer and accept it.

Comment: I have added my answer. I get a message saying I can accept my own answer in two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find how to display the call stack window: while debugging, in the Debug menu, select Windows > Call Stack.

This shows all the function calls down to the line where the crash happens. Solved the cause of the particular crash straight away by the way.